# Highest Mark in each course with student name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want  to get the highest mark in each course with the title of that course and student name who toke that course exam.
and i have these tables , first one students

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon Doe |
| 2 | Sarah Doe |

and Courses table

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 2 | history |

and i made a table for connecting students with courses + the mark in course exam

| student_id | course_id | exam_mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 87 |
| 1 | 2 | 60 |
| 2 | 1 | 70 |
| 2 | 2 | 90 |

so how can i query that.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you having a problem?

Comment: You join and you aggregate. Surely those are topics you have covered in your course. So give it a try. I suggest you first try finding the highest score in each class and ignoring the need to display class information and student information. Once you have that, you can extend it to match your requirements

Comment: But i see that someone has posted a solution for you - so another learning opportunity lost.

Comment: i tried a lot with it, it is the firs time that i deal with three relational tables

Comment: and i see no problem with learning from solutions in the beginning

Comment: @MahmoudHussien Please find the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions.  One method is:

```
select . . .   -- whatever columns you want
from (select sc.*,
             rank() over (partition by course_id order by exam_mark desc) as seqnum
      from student_courses sc
     ) sc join
     students s
     on sc.student_id = s.id join
     courses c
     on sc.course_id = c.id
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used RANK() with course_id partitions and exam_marks desc order to get the ranking. then select the ranking = 1 to get the highest value of the ranking. Windows functions are super useful for these type of qestions.

```
SELECT 
  A.[CourseId]
 ,A.[exam_mark]
 ,A.[name]
 ,A.[title]
FROM
(
     SELECT
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [mark].[course_id]   ORDER BY  [mark].[exam_mark] DESC ) AS [rnk] 
     ,[Courses].[id] AS [CourseId]
     ,[Courses].[title] 
     ,[mark].[exam_mark]
     ,[students_].[name]
   FROM mark
       INNER JOIN  students_ 
             ON  mark.student_id = students_.id
       INNER JOIN  Courses 
             ON  mark.course_id = Courses.id

  ) AS A 
   WHERE A.rnk = 1
```

[image: Result]